# Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 5

Tags: java, postgresql

I get this error "Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 5." when I run the following code:

```
public void callPro(int id) {
        int inv_id = id;
        int cust_id = 0;
        try {
            Connection conn = connect();
            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = inventory_held_by_customer(?)}");
            cstmt.setInt(2, inv_id);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
            cstmt.execute();
            cust_id = cstmt.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(cust_id);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions to solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix, I missed "call" keyword inside the prepareCall's statement: CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call inventory_held_by_customer(?)}");